# whatever we write in that textbox it should save in the below column

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<h3 class="color-primary" style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">Options</h3>
<button md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-mini add-task" (click)="addOptions.show()">
    <md-icon style="color:white;">add</md-icon>
</button>
```

The above code is a button. If we clicked on this button, the textbox should display below the button and whatever we write in that textbox it should save in the below column.

Comment: Are you saying that clicking the button should *create* and display a textbox? What if the button is clicked multiple times? And what is "the below column"? There is no table or column shown.

Comment: table will be there ,  this.options = [{ "name": "option1" },
            { "name": "option2", },
            { "name": "option3" },
            { "name": "option4", },
            { "name": "option5" }];
        iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('edit', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('images/icons/pencil.svg'));
        iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('save', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('images/icons/resetFilters.svg'));
    }

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant information there. Don't post code in comments. You seem to be saying that the values entered should be added to the `this.options` array, but it isn't clear. (Also, the code you put in that comment is talking about an icon registry, but your question was just about text in a textbox. If they're related somehow please explain that. Otherwise don't include the icon stuff.)

Comment: if i click that icon i should get textbox and if we input in textbox then it should save in below .